# Can I insert a List of doubles or Strings in sqlite table in flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I want to insert two lists in my sqlite table in flutter, one containing names and other containing doubles. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean add a list of strings, where each string as an entry, or each entry is a list of strings?

Comment: Each entry is a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

There is no datatype in sqlite that accepts lists. But you can still do this using json encoding. Have a look at the official docs here : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

You basically encode your data into json, save it as a String to sqlite, and then decode it again when you pull it out of sqlite.